# How can I block input after JQuery Validation SubmitHandler and Form.Submit succeeds?

Tags: jquery, validation, onsubmit

I've got 2 methods of validation in my Form.
a.  JQuery Validation
b.  A couple complicated hardcoded rules in Form.Submit() handlers.

I need to disable the submit button once BOTH a & b validation has succeeded so that the user doesn't submit twice.

My best attempt so far involves adding a "submitHandler" to the JQuery Validation as so...

```
jQuery("#myForm").validate(
{
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit({
            success: function (submittedForm, action) {
                alert("submitting");
                $('input[type=submit]', submittedForm).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Of course this doesn't seem to work.  By the time it hits the SubmitHandler both stages of validation have already been run?  If (a) JQuery Validation failed this event is not triggered.  However, if (b) Custom validation failed then it is run although the form is not submitted.  If both (a & b) passed it is run however the inner "success" callback is never reached.  So my input is never disabled.

Here is an example of 1 of n submit validations (its a dynamic form there are other similar validations where .submit is used to return false when validation fails)...

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    // If one is checked they must both be checked.
    if ($(SessionRadioId_2).is(':checked') || $(SessionRadioId_4).is(':checked')) {
        if (!($(SessionRadioId_2).is(':checked')) || !($(SessionRadioId_4).is(':checked'))) {
            alert('If you plan on attending "ABC" you must select it in both Session 2 & 3.');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

Since multiple submits is what you are trying to avoid, rather than disabling the submit button *after* validation, disable it before and then re-enable it if validation fails.

Comment: Agreed this would be a suitable solution.  However, I don't see any way to hook up validationFailed event.  Remember it needs to handle the both JQuery Validation failing and OnSubmit failing.  Also what event handler can I use to disable before the validation is called?